# how to make the page redirects to the same page after the event occured

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I am trying to make a upvote and downvote functionality on my website. however there is a particular behaviour that i don't like which is that whenever a user clicks the button, he should not be redirect to another page but should remain on the same page.

What happens after clicking the upvote button is that it goes to the url `http://localhost:8001/upvote/2/` which i don't want. I want it to remain on the same page which is `http://localhost:8001/view-supplier/`

models.py

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)

    # CUSTOM USER FIELDS
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    upvotes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    downvotes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    objects = UserManager()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/users/%i/" % (self.pk)
        
    def get_email(self):
        return self.email
```

views.py

```
def Viewsupplier(request):
    title = "All Suppliers"
    suppliers = User.objects.filter(user_type__is_supplier=True)

    context = {"suppliers":suppliers, "title":title}

    return render(request, 'core/view-suppliers.html', context)

@login_required
def upvote(request, pk):
    supplier_vote = get_object_or_404(User, id=pk)
    supplier_vote.upvotes += 1
    supplier_vote.save()
    upvote_count = supplier_vote.upvotes
    context = {"supplier_vote":supplier_vote, "upvote_count":upvote_count}
    return render(request, "core/view-suppliers.html", context)

@login_required
def downvote(request, pk):
    supplier_vote = get_object_or_404(User, id=pk)
    supplier_vote.downvotes -= 1
    supplier_vote.save()
    downvote_count = supplier_vote.downvotes
    context = {"supplier_vote":supplier_vote, "downvote_count":downvote_count}
    return render(request, "core/view-suppliers.html", context)
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('upvote/<int:pk>/', views.upvote, name='upvote'),
    path('downvote/<int:pk>/', views.downvote, name='downvote'),
]
```

view-supplier.html

```
<table class="table table-borderless table-data3">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Votes</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for supplier in suppliers %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{forloop.counter}}</td>
            <td>{{supplier.country}}</td>
            <td>
                <div class="table-data-feature">
                    <a href="{% url 'upvote' supplier.id %}" class="m-r-10">
                        <button class="item" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Like">
                        <i class="zmdi zmdi-thumb-up"></i>{{upvote_count}}</button>
                    </a>
                    <a href="{% url 'downvote' supplier.id %}">
                        <button class="item" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Dislike">
                        <i class="zmdi zmdi-thumb-down"></i>{{downvote_count}}</button>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% empty %}
            <tr><td class="text-center p-5" colspan="7"><h4>No supplier available</h4></td></tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please post your `view-supplier` view

Comment: updated. check it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement an API (application programming interface) to send the upvote and downvote asynchronously. [Django REST framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) is the way to go to create your very own API. You can watch hours of video tutorials on that subject on YouTube. The docs for Django REST framework is really great and easy to read as well. Django is a server-side web-framework which means that it can only help you if you submit to the server.  You can definitely reload the same page:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('<app_name>:<url_name>'))
```

However, there will be an  interruption. So, the recommended way to handle this type of behavior is through asynchronous call using JavaScript's APIs such as the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) to the REST framework.

If, for probably misplaced fear of learning asynchronous coding, you decide to send data to your server the old-fashion way, you can always use your upvote and downvote to submit user data and update the counts.  Then, in your view_supplier view, you need to get the updated view count and pass it to the context.  So, your upvote view changes the upvote counts and trigger the Viewsupplier view. Then, inside the ViewSupplier view, you get the counts and add it to the context

```
# in your template
<a href="{% url 'upvote' supplier.id %}" class="m-r-10">
   <button class="item" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Like">
   <i class="zmdi zmdi-thumb-up"></i>{{upvote_count}}</button>
</a>

# in your view
def Viewsupplier(request):
    title = "All Suppliers"
    suppliers = User.objects.filter(user_type__is_supplier=True)

    # Get the updated count:
    suppliers_votes_count = {}
    for supplier in suppliers:
        upvote_count    = supplier.upvotes
        downvote_count  = supplier.upvotes

        supplier_count = {supplier: {'upvote': upvote_count, 'downvote': downvote_count } }
    
    suppliers_votes_count.update(supplier_count)

    context = {"suppliers":suppliers, "title":title, "suppliers_votes_count": suppliers_votes_count }

    return render(request, 'core/view-suppliers.html', context)

@login_required
def upvote(request, pk):
    supplier_vote = get_object_or_404(User, id=pk)
    supplier_vote.upvotes += 1
    supplier_vote.save()
    upvote_count = supplier_vote.upvotes
    context = {"supplier_vote":supplier_vote, "upvote_count":upvote_count}
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('core:view_supplier'))
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution but how do i implement the "return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('<app_name>:<url_name>'))" and "return render(request, "core/view-suppliers.html", context)" together in the same view.

Comment: Thanks for the solution

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily achieved by using AJAX.

Rather than providing the `supplier_id` as part of URL, it would be better to send the `supplier_id` in AJAX to your Django Upvote view. You could do like this.

**HTML:**

```
<button id="{{ supplier_id }}" class="item upvote" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Like">
<i class="zmdi zmdi-thumb-up"></i>{{upvote_count}}
</button>
```

Extract the `supplier_id` from the button on click event using Javascript.

**JavaScript:**

```
$('.upvote').on('click', function () {
var supp_id = $(this).attr('id');
  $ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/upvote/',
    data: {
       supplier_id: supplier_id,
    },
   success: function (data) {
   if (data.status == 'success') {
       /* Your upvote logic like updating the color of button or showing Unlike etc.,*/
    }
  }
 });
});
```

Change your url pattern in Django **urls.py** to

`urlpatterns = [path('upvote/', views.upvote, name='upvote'),`

**Views.py**

```
def upvote(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        supplier_id = request.POST['supplier_id']
        # Your DB update logic goes here....
        return JsonResponse({'status': 'success'})
    else:
        return JsonResponse({'status': 'Error'})
```

*Similarly you could do the same for `downvote`.*

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would achieve this:

first I'd have simple forms handling the upvotes/downvotes:

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'view-supplier' %}"> //upvote form
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="hidden" name="upvote-button">
  <button type="submit" style="width:100%">Upvote Button</button>
</form>

<form method="POST" action="{% url 'view-supplier' %}"> // downvote form
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="hidden" name="downvote-button">
  <button type="submit" style="width:100%">Downvote Button</button>
</form>
```

Then I'd have the view set up like:

```
def supplierView(request):
   supplier_vote = get_object_or_404(User, id=pk)

   if 'upvote-button' in request.POST:
         supplier_vote.upvotes += 1
         supplier_vote.save()
         upvote_count = supplier_vote.upvotes

   elif 'downvote-button' in request.POST:
         supplier_vote.downvotes -= 1
         supplier_vote.save()
         downvote_count = supplier_vote.downvotes
   
   else:
         downvote_count = supplier_vote.downvotes
         upvote_count = supplier_vote.upvotes

   context = {
    'upvote_count': upvote_count,
    'downvote_count': upvote_count,
   }

   return render(request, 'main/view-suppliers.html', context)
```

This way when someone clicks the upvote button, they're redirected to the same view, which then handles adding the upvotes and updates the context.

If `view-supplier` is a detail view, you'll also have to pass in the PK to the view.

Comment: Thanks anthony but i get the error "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'upvote_count' referenced before assignment" after using your codes

Comment: also, the "viewsupplier" view is a list view. since i have to migrate the codes from the initial view, the upvote and downvote which initially had the pk attribute with the request, how can i make that also possible in the "viewsSupplier" view.